# How to identify Asterisk SIP Messaging delievered and seen status?

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am developing a basic C# chat application using Asterisk SIP messaging. I am using Independentsoft as a SIP.Net wrapper. I can send and receive message using asterisk server. But, I would like to implement a feature like delivered and seen status in my application.

For Delivered status (I used 200 Ok response from client once the message delivered).
For Seen status (I sent a code as message if user window opened) and updated the seen status in UI.

Is there any other way I can send a response for seen message? I just need some suggestions to make a good code structure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk is not messanger. It not produce ANY events unless you specified that in dialplan.

For messanger use jabberD or create dialplan which will notify you about delivery.

Seen status can be sent only by end-user softphone(for example send back other events with special word).